# Falcon app using Gunicorn on Heroku stalls

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn, falconframework

I am trying to serve a falcon app on Heroku using gunicorn.

I pretty much followed the falcon docs and created a basic application.

I am using psycopg2 to add a connection cursor to each Resource when processing requests.

```
web: gunicorn app:api --log-level=DEBUG --worker-class=gevent
```

But right now every request results in a timeout:

```
Feb 06 18:10:01 d.19db00e4-faf8-47bc-aaea-c78a52163a24 heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=falcon-raptor-api.herokuapp.com request_id=3b29350f-8990-430c-92e8-02458d91a2f9 fwd="54.91.242.125" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

I think this is an issue with psycopg2 or gunicorn or both.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue deploying a Falcon API with Gunicorn on Heroku. My issue was that I was not using Gunicorn's `bind` argument, so there was no socket to listen to. Heroku uses dynamic port numbers, so it's best to just use the `$PORT` var. Try something like this in your Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:api --log-level=DEBUG --worker-class=gevent
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a blocking call is being made inside a gevent greenthead. Make sure you manually patch or monkey patch the relevant networking libraries (socket, psycopg2, etc.) as early as possible during your application.

See [Using gevent monkey patching with threading makes thread work serially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192539/using-gevent-monkey-patching-with-threading-makes-thread-work-serially)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Falcon in Heroku.

Use following in proc file

```
web: gunicorn api:app --log-level=DEBUG --worker-class=gevent
```

Here I am assuming that you want to run "api.py" file using Gunicorn in Heroku.

I hope this will solve your problem.