# How to receive data from python Thread in a greenlet without blocking all greenlets?

Tags: python-multithreading, gevent

We have an existing codebase that is heavily `Thread` based which we're trying to expose through flask-socketio. I can't find a mechanism to have a greenlet wait for data from a Thread without blocking all of gevent or through a polling loop.

I thought maybe I could use an unbounded gevent `Queue` and call `put` from the `Thread` but that didn't seem to work. Also, the application is not performant enough with long polling so we can't use threads for socketio.

Is there a mechanism to receive data from the `Thread` in a greenlet without the greenlet blocking all of gevent?

Comment: Did you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192539/using-gevent-monkey-patching-with-threading-makes-thread-work-serially

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Do you mean monkey patching threads with gevent? The threaded code we have definitely needs multiple cores. It's highly unlikely it would work with monkey patching or gevent.